# How OK or not OK is it to consequently delete correct answers

Tags: discussion

I couldn't help noticing a small group of players very consequently deletes all my answers, leaving questions with heavily biased answers only.
Aside from it being annoying to have players launch personal attacks on me, it leaves all remaining answers to be massively opinion based, thereby eligible for deletion.
How is that OK and what can be done about it if it isn't?

Comment: Let's start here; have you taken the time to read the [help] and find out a little about how this place works, and is different from other online communities you might be more familiar with?

Comment: @Jamiec It is a game. I got that far and that was totally disappointing. Add to that the fact that most people who come here don't know it's a game and you got something pretty darn evil. Anything about the Boeing 737 Max is completely dominated by fanatics that have either no clue or are protecting their business.

Comment: @Jamiec I am a bit naive, that is true. I am still trying to contribute something, but that somehow seems to be not the point. I did learn a few things too, which is interesting, but this whole moderation game lives a life of its own that doesn't seem to care about the questions or the answers. In favor of the first I question the latter. Both are here.

Comment: It seems to me that you are too focused on voicing your (justified) criticism of the 737 rather than specifically answering the question above you.

Comment: Seeing as what you're really talking about is the bad reception your 3 answers on the MCAS question has received - I have left a comment on the 1 remaining one illustrating why I think it is a bad answer, and by extension why I downvoted it.

Comment: @Jamiec The essence of my answer is that the objective of MCAS is not to adjust the pitch but the pitch trim, which is exactly what MCAS does. That doesn't seem like a big difference, but considering the consequences it makes all the difference. It turns MCAS into a primary flight control system. That message completely drowns.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question given, deleting someone else’s correct answer is not OK unless it does not make a contribution to the site. What must be determined before deletion would be:

1. Does the answer actually answer the question?
2. Is the answer correct?
3. Does the answer give more pertinent information, new information, clarification of previously given information, or an explanation of already given information than a previous answer has given?
4. Is the answer simply opinion based or written in a way that does not promote actual facts?
5. Does the answer include verifiable references and citations from reputable sources? This is highly important?
6. Does the answer lead to further discussion more than it answers the actual question?
7. Is the answer well written and understandable?
8. Is the answer simply a rant?
9. Is the answer disparaging or adversarial?
10. Does the answer contribute to the general knowledge on the site per the site guidelines? Does it even follow site guidelines?

I am not that familiar with you and your posts. From the posts that I have found specifically on AviationStackExchange, many of them if not the majority violate one or more of the above tenants.

This is not a situation that can not be fixed and overcome so that you are a valuable contributor to this site. You seem to be very knowledgeable. But, if the writing style of this site is not to your liking, there are other sites which are tailored more towards open discussion, spitballing of ideas, and debate. Might I recommend Quora or Reddit?

This site is not to the tastes of everyone. It is not a game. The points are just to incentivize people to post the most correct and constructive contributions.

It has its advantages and its disadvantages. Due to its restrictive nature, it garners a lot fewer new questions and contributions than most sites. But, its restrictive nature produces answers that are more correct and factual than other site. IMHO.

Comment: Consider replacing "correct" with "factually accurate"

Comment: All of your 10 points are good points to differentiate *good* and *poor* answers, but not all of them are applicable to deletion. See [this help center page](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) for the *official* list of reasons.

Comment: @DeanF. Following these points appears to be subject to interpretation. Sometimes people read things in my words I didn't write. Me minding the writing style of the site is not an issue either, but the other way around is. I am trying to get a point across that is both controversial as well as not documented. Getting a reader to follow the same mind path to come to the same conclusion (or be able to contradict it with argument) is very hard. I have to make it obvious, but even if I succeed in doing that, some readers have things to loose in this. Unpopularity doesn't make answers 'incorrect'

Comment: @Berend - As Abdullah points out, you may view your answer as correct. But, is it factually accurate? And, can that be proven or documented. In general, this site tries not to be a site for debating opinions. Nor is it a site for arguing pints of view.

Comment: @DeanF. To me its factually correct, but that is not based on documents. Anything official in that direction would get attacked immediately. To convince, I try to get attention for things that are known facts, but simply don't get attention. 'Normal' airplanes can not crash due to failing trim. Even on the 737 Max it was not just not supposed to happen, it was supposed to be impossible. That fact is absolutely crucial but completely ignored. Not denied, just ignored.

Comment: Actually, my point was that "correct" in this context is ambiguous, at least to @Berend if not to us. Eg when askedt "What is the problem supposed to be solved by MCAS?' the answer "MCAS had a single point of failure and also the entire 737 family had a design flaw" may be factually accurate, but not correct. (Or, as you say, vice versa)

Comment: @Abdullah The point I am trying to make is that MCAS does NOT have a single point of failure. MCAS would not lead to a crash if applied on any other aircraft. What caused the crashes is the fact that the aerodynamic authority of the trim surfaces exceeds that of the elevators. That is not supposed to be possible. Those same trim surfaces are on every 737. I am still trying to find an understandable way to directly link the need for MCAS to that fact.

Comment: You see what happens? And this happens all the time. No argument, no comment, just simply refusal, like being in brain locked a state of denial. The moment I come close to making clear why it can't be anything else, the lights just go out. And in the mean time answers that are not just wrong, but utterly misleading get voted up like there's a price on it, which by the way there is.

Comment: @Bianfable: FWIW, for trusted users there's also [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), where low-quality beyond repair is a good enough reason. A good measure would be the votes and/or comments on the post that highlight the issue(s).

Comment: How does that help me from talking to a bunch of flat-earthers? There is nothing Laws-Of-Physics about this issue. All you have to do to understand what is going on is look at what is smack in front of you, being as blatantly obvious as it gets. The essential difference between elevators and trim surfaces is not just the way they are controlled, but also the fact that these differences make them not interchangeable, meaning the first absolutely 100%  guaranteed always has to be able to overpower the latter, to keep it from effectively becoming the latter, which is illegal.

Comment: According to the FAA regulations for pitch control surfaces, what happened to these two Max's should have been absolutely impossible, regardless of MCAS or no MCAS.

Comment: When Airbus created the A320, they did have to live up to the demands, leaving them with no choice but to make their aircraft entirely computer controlled, thereby annihilating the difference between elevators and pitch trim surfaces, since the same system controls both, making them perfectly interchangeable. From there on, all they had to do, was to wait for the 737 fix to go sour.

Comment: When you pitch up an aircraft with oversized pitch trim, the pressure on the elevator surfaces reduces with increasing angle, which is countered by a reduced amount of elevator input. The pressure on the trim surfaces reduces as well, but their input stays the same.  If you don't change trim pitch control, then somewhere down the line you will have to push the elevators down in order to overcome the uncompensated loss of pressure on the trim surfaces. So Boeing made the trim surfaces change automatically, which would have worked on any other airplane, but not on the 737.

Comment: The FAA, realizing it was partially responsible for the issue becoming an issue in the first place, did the one thing they shouldn't have done. They eased up the certification of MCAS, allowing it to be deployed while being way less reliable than it should have been. Does that explain why MCAS exists?  Yes of course! The engines only play a minor role in this whole situation, by making the critical angle for this come down into the flight envelope. If pitched up high enough, every 737 shows this effect. Not just the Max.

Comment: Can any one of the people who would love to downvote this and delete this and forget they ever saw it, please, please pretty please with sugar on top and cream on the side come up with a half way solid reason why this should be anything other than the one right answer to the question it was intended to answer in the first place?

Comment: *Point 2: is the answer correct* is not relevant for deletion. A well argued, but demonstrable wrong answer, should be **down-voted but not deleted**. From help *Voting up a question or answer signals to the rest of the community that a post is interesting, well-researched, and useful, while voting down a post signals the opposite: that the post contains wrong information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate information.*

Answer (score 0):

I know of only one user who can be said to have "attacked" you. And while I must admit to being surprised by the large number of downvotes appearing on seemingly *all* of your answers, given how they are in harmony with those of some of our top contributers, I would advise against jumping to conclusions. Instead, I recommend that you ask clarification for each individual case of deleted answers. This is especially ttue given how I have found a good reason for one deletion.

Meanwhile, I wish the rest of you would cut him some slack, given how unfamiliar he is to the site, and doesn't even appear to speak English.

Comment: You found a good reason to delete and you think I don't want to know that reason? I have specifically asked for arguments and criticism, but these deletions come without comment. How would I get clarification for a deletion?

Comment: You read the posts. MCAS is a Mad Max solution on top of another Mad Max solution, which is sort of the essence of the whole thing. Why delete that?

Comment: @Berend I explained the reason for deletion in the relevant comment thread. You read and replied to my explanation

Comment: I was trying to point out the elephant in the room, but all you could read was "MCAS was a bad idea" so I tried again, and again. And now I'm here.

Comment: @Berend "Why delete that" - because it's basically opinion, and we're more interested in facts. Stick to _just answering the question_ with facts and references and leave your personal opinions at the door.

Comment: @Jamiec [possible precedent?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/86466/45534)

Comment: Or, at a minimum, answer the question with facts, then clearly differentiate your opinion at the end. Of course, I understand the confusion - in days of yore, the newspaper used to have an "Opinion/Editorial" section which was dedicated to people who wanted to give their opinions and beliefs, while the rest of the paper was _more_ focused on facts without opinion. Today's news is mostly opinion, so most folks confuse opinion with fact.

Comment: @FreeMan That is what I'm trying to do, just line up facts. The 'opinion' comments don't refute those facts. They just categorically stamp the entire post as opinion. The main thing that seems so constitute an accepted 'fact' is that it is someone else's opinion too. There is no "That is incorrect because this something contradicting is correct." comment. Someone wrote:he's a Max pilot so he knows better. How do you argue with that?